# “It has been a tough day” vs. “it is a tough day”

Tags: present-perfect, present-tense

We have discussed Present Perfect versus Past Simple in ["It has been on the news" vs. "it was on the news"](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/7206/it-has-been-on-the-news-versus-it-was-on-the-news). Now I'm asking about Present Perfect versus Present Simple.

I know that the sentence in Present Perfect, "it has been a tough day", implies that the day is still going. But would it not be much easier to say "it is a tough day"? Because if a day is tough, you just say that the day is tough.

What does using Present Perfect add to the statement?

Answer (score 2):

When using **it is a tough day**, we are negating the possible case when the future events might not be as tough. As you mention yourself:

> "it has been a tough day", **implies** that the day is *still going*.

When we use **it has been**, we are also considering the possibility that it (*the day*) might get better at some later stage.